# How to highlight an object's outline of a specific color which is visible through all other objects IN GODOT3?

Tags: shader, godot, gdscript

To all the Godot 3D experts here, can anyone please tell me how I can highlight any object's outline so that is is visible through all other objects? also highlighting any general mesh this way? or am I on the wrong platform?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is an **outline or silhouette shader**,

that you can take control of ther **render priority**

Something like this?
https://godotshaders.com/shader/outline-silhouette-shader/

Comment: Yes, OP wants something like that. I also found that shader, but I could not get correct result using it on my end, which is why I didn't post it as an answer. Did it work for you? Can you explain how to set it up? I'm aware it has to be split in multiple render passes, but, as I was saying I didn't get the correct result.